# check the files which are into database but not into the folder

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check the images which are into the database but not into the the my folder.So what i do to show all the images which are not into my folder but into my database.I fetch image name from table and store it into an array.

```
$abc = array();
$pqr = array();
$xyz = array();
$q1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rr2s4_cma_images");

while($q2=mysql_fetch_array($q1)) {
    $abc = $q2['image_name'];
    $pqr = $q2['type'];
    $xyz[] = $abc."".$pqr;
    echo "<pre>";
}
print_r($xyz);
```

For example:
This is my table

| id | image_name |

```
| 1  | 6667136_2.jpg |

| 2  | 6667136_2.jpg |

| 3  | 6667141_2.jpg |
```

This is my files which are in folder

```
6667136_2.jpg
6667141_2.jpg
```

Now i want to display the image **6667136_2.jpg** which is into my database but not into my folder.

Comment: why don't you use `file_exists` to check if image exists on folder when you are getting from database in while loop?

Comment: vinay kapoor  check the answers below

Answer (score 0):

If you have the image in database in one array `$arrayDBImages` and the image in folder in another `$arrayFolderImages` you could use

```
$resultArray = array_diff($arrayDBImages ,$arrayFolderImages );
```

in $resultArry  you have the difference between the two arrays

or for file_exists()  you should iterate

```
$path ='/path/to';

 foreach( $arrayDBImages as $key => $value) {
       if (  !file_exists ($path. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value){
          echo "$value";
       }
 }
```

Comment: how to i use file_exists instead of  array_diff?

Comment: u have any idea about file_exist function for this code

Comment: Once you have the list of files on db you can scand your dir and check with file_exists

Comment: $arrayImages means array of images which are fetch from database?

Comment: what we write in DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ?

Comment: DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR  is a PHP costant  .. for the correct separator  between part of directory  name  ..check for PHP manual

Comment: $path ='D:/xampp/htdocs/cribsuite/images/shortlistings';
 foreach( $xyz as $key => $value) 
  {

  
       if (!file_exists ($path. .$value)
    {
          echo "$value";
       } 
   } i rewrite the code like this sbut i get error

Comment: you missed  directory_separator   ($path. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$value)

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_diff() to do this. This will compare the values (not the keys)

```
    <?php
      $a1=array(
                "1"=>"d",
                "2"=>"c",
                "3"=>"b",
                "4"=>"a"
      );
      $a2=array(
                "1"=>"a",
                "2"=>"b",
                "3"=>"c"
      );

      $result=array_diff($a1,$a2);
      print_r($result);
    ?>
```

This will print 'd'

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `file_exists` when getting filename from database to check if its exists in folder.

```
$abc = array();
$pqr = array();
$xyz = array();
$q1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rr2s4_cma_images");
while($q2=mysql_fetch_array($q1))
{
    if(!file_exists($q2['image_name'])) {
        $abc = $q2['image_name'];
        $pqr = $q2['type'];
        $xyz[] = $abc."".$pqr;
        echo "<pre>";
    }
}
print_r($xyz);
```